# String with dd/MM/yyyy format to Date time irrespective of System date time format

Tags: c#, .net

Actually I m trying to convert a string to DateTime in `dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss` format using `DateTime.ParseExact`

```
String MCdatetime = "10-05-2018 15:20:00";
Datetime DBdatetime = DateTime.ParseExact(MCdatetime, "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None);
```

My System date time is in `MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss` format.
After executing above code in `C#`, `DBdatetime` is saved as `05-10-2018 15:20:00` even though I parsed as `dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss`.
I want to save always in `dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss` format irrespective of system date time format.Anyone please reply.

Comment: _"DateTime in dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss format"_ a `DateTime` has no format. Use parameterized queries to save this `DateTime` in your database.

Comment: "05-10-2018 15:20:00" is how you visualize the value in your sql client program; it shows the date in the MM-dd-yyyy format. The actual value is effectively what you expect.

Comment: What you are seeing in the debug window is ToString being called on the instance. As Tim already stated DateTime instances do not have a format, they are not stored as strings (in memory or in a persistence store when using a similar type). You have parsed it correctly and can go on to the next task/step in your assignment/project/whatever.